# Android: override onPostExecute() if AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable()) is invoked in a method

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a method which I want to execute on a background thread:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        foo();
    }

    public static void foo(){
        AsyncTask.execute(() -> {
            // perform some object creations
        });
    }

    public static void foo2(){
      // Method that updates UI (lists and views) which requires the main thread.
    }
}
```

I would like to execute `foo2` when `AsynTask` is complete i.e. `onPostExecute()`. How can I override `onPostExecute()` in this case?

Comment: Using `AsyncTask.execute(Runnable)` you can't override `onPostExecute`. You should create a new `AsyncTask` or create your class which extends `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

You cant achieve directly ,You can do through extend the Async class.

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful, You can achieve this by class instead of method. Please try the below snippet:

```
@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      foo asyncTask=new foo();
      asyncTask.execute();

   }

private class foo extends AsyncTask<void, void, void> {
      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();

      }
      @Override
      protected void doInBackground(String... strings) {

      }
      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute() {
         super.onPostExecute();
         foo2 asyncTask=new foo2();
         asyncTask.execute();
      }
   }

private class foo2 extends AsyncTask<void, void, void> {
      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();

      }
      @Override
      protected void doInBackground(String... strings) {

      }
      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute() {
         super.onPostExecute();

      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Work For me

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Do background 
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
        foo2();
    }
}

void foo2(){
    //your function
}
```

> If you want to perform some function once the Asynctask is complete,
>   You can also update the UI from within onPostExecute, which is simpler
>   if it works for you.